# Does Amazon have an API for searching products on their site for mashing up?

Tags: api, amazon-product-api

I'd like to use the Amazon product set as part of another product. Ideally we would be using the images and IDs on a mobile app as a unique identifier for products in our app.

Does such a thing exist? Is this within the usage guidelines of the API? If so, what are the requirements for our application.

Comment: IIRC, Amazon refuses that you use its APIs from a mobile device at all, so that's pretty moot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately Amazon's TOS does not permit usage of their Product Advertising API (the one with product info and images) in mobile device applications.

See http://techcrunch.com/2009/07/07/amazon-killing-mobile-apps-that-use-its-data/
and https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/gp/advertising/api/detail/agreement.html